# Bluetooth stopped working - HERA

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

Bluetooth is dead.

Yesterday it worked, today it's not.

I checked common points like:

- **systemctl restart bluetooth**
- cat /etc/bluetooth/main.con ....**AutoEnable=true**
- **rfkill**

ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD

0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked

MX-Master Mouse works on my other PC's/Distros.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with the latest OS round of updates from the past couple of days. Booting into the OS with Bluetooth-USB dongle keyboard and mouse leaves them inoperative and the keyboard refuses to work even when plugged in via the USB cable directly. After the login screen is shown, the keyboard's led for connection flashes a couple of times and then all the leds power off (Logitech G915 TKL). Both the GRUB menu and the other OS's on the same PC work fine. The problems also disappear when booting into the recovery (5.4.0-54 or 5.4.0-58) and then choosing the resume booting option.

This is what recovery booting process shows:
[image: Recovery boot with 5.4.0-54]

Possibly USB related?

Comment: After many reboots with more kernel versions' recovery, turning on/off physically the bluetooth devices, running the other OS that has other bluetooth/wireless (vr) dongles attached, and after using the linux recovery option Dpkg - repair broken packages, my OS boots normally now. I can't tell which one fixed the error, if any. Possibly not software related, but bios/mb related.